Why is Markdown not italicizing part of my sentence?
I have the following Markdown expression: _(zh_Hans)_ and _(en)_.
This is what it looks like normally:

(zh_Hans) and (en)

I am aware I made a mistake by not putting a \ in zh_hans, but why does it syntactically look the same as if I had put the \ there (i.e. _(zh\_Hans)_ and _(en)_)?

Which markdown parsing and rendering implementations are you using?

@jsejcksn It seems to happen with all markdown editors/viewers I have tested, including Discord, Github, VSCode, and this site, which leads me to believe it's due to some sort of syntax.

To close the itatlics, it needs to be a word boundary - so e.g. _zh_.Hans_ would need to be _zh\_.Hans_ or you get: zh.Hans_ not zh_.Hans

^ @Lume I ask because providing a complete answer will involve quoting a not-insignificant amount of the CommonMark specification. Have you reviewed section 6.2 Emphasis and strong emphasis? It has the information which explains how parsing should work regarding the question that you asked.

@jsejcksn I was not aware such a site existed, so no I have not looked at that, however, I did find the part relevant to my question ("Many implementations have also restricted intraword emphasis to the * forms, to avoid unwanted emphasis in words containing internal underscores."), so thanks for linking that!

^ @Lume No problem. Hopefully you now have some better context for my previous comment, and can understand why the question is currently too vague for a useful answer — the best you could get is either “it’s probably a case of disallowed intraword emphasis” (which isn’t very helpful on its own), or copying+pasting a sizable section from that specification. At any rate, unless you can narrow down a specific implementation and provide a link to its source code, no one here can provide an answer that isn’t basically a guess.
